# Check the received HTTP response in JMeter and pass/fail test accordingly

Tags: jmeter

I have made a `TestPlan` in JMeter. I want to test a failure scenario i.e. the test should pass if failure happens. How can I do this in JMeter?

I have added a `Thread group`, a `configuration`, an `httprequest` and a `tree listener`.

When I run the test (send a signin request of an invalid user), I get ab error from server (200 OK with error message as message body).

I can't find where (and how) I should check the response. Is it in `Listeners`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JMeter builtin solution is [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)

> Assertions are used to perform additional checks on samplers, and are processed after every sampler in the same scope. To ensure that an Assertion is applied only to a particular sampler, add it as a child of the sampler.

In a general case, [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) with your expected text/regex

> response assertion control panel lets you add pattern strings to be compared against various fields of the request or response. The pattern strings are:
>
> - Contains, Matches: Perl5-style regular expressions
> - Equals, Substring: plain text, case-sensitive

You also have more specific assertions as [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion)

> component allows you to perform validations of JSON documents

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) so you can conditionally fail the request if it doesn't contain the data you expect to be there and contains the data which should not be there.

For example this configuration checks the response for absence of `error` line:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)